# Подмена значения переменной через ссылку с#

Tags: c#

В приложенном коде (код упрощен) я, по замыслу, желал переназначить значение переменной с помощью буферной другой. В процессе я понял, что делаю это неверно, т.к. кличка питомца все же выдавалась изначальная. Как же мне, выполнить  это преобразование?

```
namespace Project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Animal[,] Animals = new Animal[10, 10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    Animals[i,j] = new Animal(0,0,"Unknow");

            //FindCat(Animals) = new Cat(FindCat(Animals).X, FindCat(Animals).Y, "Jake");
            //Ошибка компиляции, "иду иным путем"

            Animal Buffer = FindCat(Animals);
            Buffer = new Cat(Buffer.X, Buffer.Y, "Jake");
            //Не работает и при 
            //Buffer = new Cat(FindCat(Animals).X, FindCat(Animals).Y, "Jake");
            Console.Write(Animals[5,5].Name);//Unknow!
            Console.Read();
        }

        static Animal FindCat(Animal[,] a)
        {
            //На деле выбор сложнее, но не думаю, что столь важно то,
            //как выбирается индекс здесь, но выбор обязателен
            return a[5, 5];
        }
    }

    class Animal
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Y;
        public int X;

        public Animal() { }
        public Animal(int x, int y, string name)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    class Cat : Animal
    {
        public string Color;

        public Cat(int x, int y, string name)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы хоть сами понимаете что делаете? Создаёте объект, назначаете его другой переменной и тутже создаёте в ней новый объект. Естественно Вам выдаст "Jake"

Comment: В вашем абстрактном примере вообще неясно зачем нужна промежуточная переменная `Pet`.

Comment: а на какой идее основан ваш код?

Comment: Суть в том, что в оригинале я экземляр класса Tile заменяю его дочерним классом Ocean, изменяя из четырех переменных лишь одну - название, а остальные - передавая по аргументам конструктора. Промежуточную переменную вводил лишь затем, что напрямую обращаться через `MyWorld.GetTurf(TurfX, TurfY) = new Ocean(...TurfX, ...TurfY, 6, ...TileType);` выходит чрезвычайно длинно и некрасиво.

Comment: Ну так приведите пример, что именно вы делаете. Сейчас это выглядит так: вы привели пример, вам ответили, а вы говорите - но я же делаю совсем не так

Comment: уберите Buffer = new Cat(Buffer.X, Buffer.Y, "Jake"); и поставте Buffer.Name="Jake"

Comment: @Grundy, @ДмитрийЧистик - Что вы набросились на человека? Надо просто объяснить разницу между объектом и ссылкой на него. Очевидно же, что ТС ожидал, что присвоение нового значения переменной `Buffer`: `Buffer = new Cat(...);` изменит значение элемента массива `Animals[5, 5]`, что, конечно, не так.

Comment: Дмитрий, но тогда Animal не станет классом Cat, а это важно.

Comment: @Igor, это надо просто подходящий дубликат найти, а поиск на русском - печален :)

Comment: @Igor Этот человек понял меня точно. Т.е. заменить через "=" я могу лишь обращаясь к оригиналу, но не к ссылке? По ссылке изменяются лишь переменные класса, на который ссылка?

Comment: @cage, а может не стоит сначала заполнять одним типом, а потом пытаться подменить вторым? Посмотрите об [ошибке XY](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy)

Comment: @cage - Присвоение нового значения переменной `Buffer` изменит куда показывает переменная (ссылка, reference) `Buffer`, а переменная (ссылка, reference) `Animals[5, 5]` будет продолжать показывать на старый объект.

Comment: @Grundy - Я просто расстроился от первой фразы Дмитрия: "Вы хоть сами понимаете что делаете?".

Comment: @Igor, да, резковато :)

Comment: Благодарю за терпение. Я просто ожидал, что каким-то образом можно имея ссылку на объект его заменить на этом самом месте другим.

Comment: @cage - Этого можно достичь, если хранить в массиве не ссылки непосредственно на объекты типа `Animal` (и его наследников), а объекты, которые содержат эти ссылки см. добавление к ответу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Присвоение нового значения переменной `Buffer` (`Buffer = new Cat(...);`) изменит куда указывает переменная (ссылка, reference) `Buffer`, а переменная (ссылка, reference) `Animals[5, 5]` будет продолжать указывать на старый объект.

```
static Animal GetAtCatPosition(Animal[,] animals)
{
  return animals[5, 5];
}

static void PutAtCatPosition(Animal[,] animals, Animal a)
{
  animals[5, 5] = a;
}

Animal Buffer = GetAtCatPosition(Animals);
PutAtCatPosition(Animals, new Cat(Buffer.X, Buffer.Y, "Jake"));
```

*Вариант 2 (Омега) [Fundamental theorem of software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering):*

```
public class AnimalHolder
{
  public Animal Animal { get; set; }
}

static AnimalHolder FindCat(AnimalHolder[,] a)
{
  return a[5, 5];
}

AnimalHolder[,] Animals = new AnimalHolder[10, 10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    Animals[i,j] = new AnimalHolder() { Animal = new Animal(0, 0, "Unknown") };

AnimalHolder Buffer = FindCat(Animals);
Buffer.Animal = new Cat(Buffer.X, Buffer.Y, "Jake");
Console.Write(Animals[5,5].Animal.Name);//Jake!
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 3):

Исправил

```
namespace Project
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AngryAnimal MyAnimal = new AngryAnimal("Jake");
        //////////////////////
        Animal Pet;
        Pet = MyAnimal;
        Pet.Name = "Jack";
        Console.Write(MyAnimal.Name);//Jack
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Animal
{
    public string Name;

    public Animal(string name, int a, int b, int c)  {Name = name;}
}

class AngryAnimal : Animal
{
  public AngryAnimal(string name) :base(name, 1, 2, 3) {}
}


}
```

Comment: В оригинале, к сожалению, я один класс подменяю дочерним (имеет более широкий спектр переменных) и потому просто изменить интересующие меня переменные не имеет смысла. (Читайте выше, в комментариях к основному посту)

Comment: @cage, ответ подходит под ваш случай

Comment: @Grundy Я обновил оригинальный пост. Простите, мне и самому неудобно за то, как некрасиво поступаю с вами, но все происходит, как вы можете видеть в оригинальном посте иначе: заменяющему дочернему элементу ПЕРЕДАЮТСЯ некоторые значения родительского и лишь одно изменяется.

Comment: @cage, в любом случае - ответ показывает как можно сделать. единственный вариант в данном случае который сработает: `a[5,5] = new Cat(...)` то есть запись напрямую в массив